# Return keyword in JavaScript, what does it do it this code?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with the return keyword in this code. I look at the return keyword and expect it to return what its followed by, in this case the number 28. I know we call the function by passing it a function but why even use return in the function call, why not just pass it a value.

```
var addTwo = function(num, fn) {
console.log(num + fn());
}

addTwo(28, function(){return 28;})
```

Comment: If you'd call `addTwo(28, 28)`, you'd be getting errors, because the second parameter for `addTwo` is expected to be a function.

Comment: Seems you just picked someone's tutorial abt something very seriously. It is just an example of using a function inside another function. It cud be done properly in mulitple lines, may be author wanted to just let ppl know possibility

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason to ever write production code like that.

It is clearly a highly simplified example to demonstrate that functions can be passed as arguments.

For a more practical example of passing functions as arguments, see the [MDN documentation for `Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 0):

You're right. In that very specific situation, there's no reason to use a function like that. Let me give you an example of when you might want to use `return`

```
function doSomeFancyMath(a, b) {
    // fancy math code goes here
    return result;
}
console.log(doSomeFancyMath(1, 2));
console.log(doSomeFancyMath(9, 100));
```

In this case, using return is advantageous because then if we want to do the fancy math more than once, we won't need to re-write it all. We can just call a function that does the fancy math.